# Berry-Esseen vs concentration inequalities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I am trying to understand a bit more how concentration inequalities work but I am having some trouble. Indeed there is this [Berry–Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem#Identically_distributed_summands) that implies that if $Z_n = (X_1+\ldots +X_n)\sqrt{n}/\sigma$ then then $Z_n\to g\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and quantitatively we have something like $\lvert P\{Z_N≥t\}−P\{g≥t\}\rvert≤\frac{C}{\sqrt{N}}$. Also it seems that this bound is tight. But the [Hoeffding bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case_of_bounded_random_variables) can bound the tail by something that looks like $e^{-t^2}$ like in the exponential. Intuitively these this seem a bit counter-intuitive and I don't get it.

Comment: Berry-Esseen tells you how close the average is to a normal distribution.  Hoeffding tells you how close the average is to its expected value.  Since normal distributions also exhibit concentration around their expected value, these are consistent with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Well. I'm not sure what you asked.
Berry-Essen and Hoeffding deal with different objects. $Z_n$, which you provided, describe how the mean of $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ distributes around $\mathbb{E}(X)$. And Berry-Essen tells you the speed at which these distributions converge to a normal law
.
While Hoeffding provides an estimation of how quick the mean $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$ converges to $\mathbb{E}(X)$.
So, one (Hoeffding) gives you a local view on the concentration while other (Berry-Essen) gives you a global estimation. And intuitively, the bound for a global estimation is less tight.
P/s: Of course, we can tout Hoeffding somehow to get some estimation on the convergence in law, but I think that is not the point. Hope this help.